# Is that possible to embbed Scheme(lisp) interpreter into iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, scripting, scheme, embedding

I'm finding embeddable Scheme interpreter(or JIT compiler or anything) into Cocoa Touch.
I think just a C compatible Scheme engine may be fine. Please recommend some. I wish it's MIT/BSD style free license, but commercials are fine too.

And.. does Apple AppStore allow embedded scripting like Scheme?

Comment: I found more suitable LISP for my needs. "Nu". It's here:
http://programming.nu/usage

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think James Long's blog is exactly what you're looking for: http://jlongster.com/software/iphone/scheme-iphone-example/

the above link is dead, try https://github.com/jlongster/gambit-iphone-example instead.

Comment: That was way easier than I thought it would be. Thanks for the pointer!

Comment: Thanks, I currently digging it:)

Comment: Nope, his site appears to be gone now. I remember seeing a post that he was switching from Scheme to Python for most of his development, though.

Answer (score 3):

You could do this so long as there was no DOWNLOADED or USER-ENTERED script/code. If all you were using Scheme for was internal scripting, that would be allowed.

Comment: Thanks! The answer one of what I wished for! Of course, all codes are my own built-ins.

Answer (score 1):

Apple allows interpreted code and scripting in an app as long as the code or scripts are not downloaded.  For instance, there are around half a dozen BASIC interpreters in the App store that allow a user to type their BASIC code in manually (but not download any) and run it in an interpreter or emulator.  Lots of games that run Lua or Mono as well.

There is no way to run any JIT compiled code on a stock iOS device.  The executable memory pages of all App store apps are marked read-only.

- Various exceptions for JavaScript, UIWebViews and Safari.

Comment: Has anyone seen the Zappar app? It downloads interactive media - now surely that could be considered as a script!
Here's a debate - when does a document format become a script?

Answer (score 0):

You may be interested in [Gambit Scheme](http://dynamo.iro.umontreal.ca/~gambit/wiki/index.php/Main_Page).

For your second question: No, Apple doesn't allow interpreted code to run in your application.

EDIT

Ben Gottlieb is right, you cannot run user-scripts in your app, but internal code interpretation is supposed to be okay.

Answer (score 0):

I believe [TinyScheme](http://tinyscheme.sourceforge.net/home.html) is used by the GIMP for its script-fu.  It's also BSD-licensed.